# How to make container communicate with SQL Server on host machine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docker, sql-server-express, docker-container

I am running an ASP.NET application in a Docker container. This application communicates with SQL Server Express which is running on the host. When I run this application, obviously it throws an error as it is unable to communicate with the SQL Server.

How do I make my application (which is running inside Docker) communicate with SQL Server running on the host or another machine?

SQL Server is accessible at `HOST_MACHINE_NAME\SQLExpress` on port 1433. This is what I am using in connection string in `web.config` but it is unable to communicate.

Comment: By default, when running a docker container, it will be using the bridge network and can communicate with the host. Can you show configuration of both `docker command` and `web.config` file?

Comment: In `web.config`, first I tried connection string `data source=WIN-A8B4E172MWEG\SQLEXPRESS, 1433;` but it didn't work. Then I tried `data source=host.docker.internal\SQLEXPRESS, 1433;` but same issue.